# Xamarin.Forms Grouped List View fails on adding new groups in Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, grouping, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms for developing mobile apps for Android and windows Phone.

I have a listview of messages which is bound to an ObservableCollection of groups.  The list groups the messages by day then the messages show in order of the time - pretty standard stuff.

The problem I have now encountered is that in Android - using the **Add** function to add new groups to the ObservableCollection causes an unhandled exception to fire.

> 04-22 13:13:32.404 D/Mono    (19971): DllImport attempting to load:
>   '/system/lib/liblog.so'. 04-22 13:13:32.404 D/Mono    (19971):
>   DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'. 04-22 13:13:32.404
>   D/Mono    (19971): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so'
>   ('/system/lib/liblog.so'). 04-22 13:13:32.404 D/Mono    (19971):
>   Searching for '__android_log_print'. 04-22 13:13:32.414 D/Mono
>   (19971): Probing '__android_log_print'. 04-22 13:13:32.414 D/Mono
>   (19971): Found as '__android_log_print'. 04-22 13:13:32.434
>   I/MonoDroid(19971): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: An unhandled exception
>   occured.
>
> 04-22 13:13:32.444 I/MonoDroid(19971):
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. 04-22
>   13:13:32.444 I/MonoDroid(19971): Parameter name: index 04-22
>   13:13:32.444 I/MonoDroid(19971): at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1<object>.get_Item (int) <0x0007c>
>   04-22 13:13:32.444 I/MonoDroid(19971): at
>   Cadenza.Collections.OrderedDictionary`2,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Cell>>.get_Item (int) <0x00063>

This is not a problem in Windows.

I can get around this by using the **AddRange** function and simply adding the item I want to add to another "temporary list" first, then add that temporary list to the main Collection - This gets around it but seems a bit of a hack.

Another way would be to do this on the main thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
   // using of add function in this manner works.
});
```

Has anyone had a similar problem and have you found a solution to it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing `Add` operations from a different threads. `ObservableCollection` is not thread safe.

- You could fix that by creating a custom thread safe `ObservableCollection` (eg. simplest one using `lock` statements or even `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` calls which will queue operations on a main thread).
- You could also use `BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization` for a collections synchronization. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19114/invalid-number-of-rows-in-section

Comment: Cheers solved this by suing the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread option

Comment: No problem. If it's working you can mark this question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @loan.burger, I got the same issue but still not fixed. Could you please show me where exactly I have to put BeginInvokeOnMainThread is?

Comment: Hi @cahyo you just call your .Add on your list in the   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{ YourList.Add(someItem); });  The reason this is needed is most likely that your adding to the list in a UI thread which blocks the UI thread and causes the app to crash because an ObservableCollection is not thread safe as Daniel explains above.  Hope that helps otherwise as a new question and present your code so we can better assist you.

Comment: Hi @loan.burger, it work. And after i try `BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization` it much simpler and cleaner for me, and i will use it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@Daniel Luberda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5064986/daniel-luberda)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31745793/5953643), I too recommend using [`BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindingbase.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=xamarin-forms&WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin), because `ObservableCollection` is not thread safe.

I put together a blog post on the topic here: https://www.codetraveler.io/2019/08/27/using-observablecollection-in-a-multi-threaded-xamarin-forms-application/

### BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization Example

**Note**: Ensure that you initialize the ObservableCollection before calling `EnableCollectionSynchronization`

```cs
class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
        Xamarin.Forms.BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization(MyCollection, null, ObservableCollectionCallback);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyCollection { get; }

    void ObservableCollectionCallback(IEnumerable collection, object context, Action accessMethod, bool writeAccess)
    {
        lock (collection)
        {
            accessMethod?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brandon - Have you tried this solution with a grouped ListView? I'm trying to at the moment and I still get the "index out of range" exception even when just adding items to the collection on the main thread.
I have a class like...
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
...
and my ListView bound to a grouped collection like.... ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, ListItemViewModel>> GroupedItems { get; set; }

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the suggestion. But however I try it, the callback function never seems to be accessed, regardless of which operations I perform on my collection. What is your recent experience? I am using Xamarin Forms 4.4 on UWP and Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Task loadLineItems = Task.Run( () =>
            {
                foreach (listEntity item in newList)
                {
                    this.ObservalCollectionFromVM.Add(item);
                }
            });
            loadLineItems.Wait();
```

or

```
            Task loadLineItems = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var list == await DependencyService.Get<IEntityService>().GetEntityListAsync();
                foreach (Entity item in list)
                {
                    this.ObservalCollectionFromVM.Add(item);
                }
            });
            loadLineItems.Wait();
```